# IdentityServer4 Maintain Session Id across different authentication flows

Tags: identityserver4

I am using Identityserver4 as an OIDC Athentication Server using both clientCredentials flow and OIDC Implicit flow. My Setup is this

Client Website (Needs a JWT for some front-end decisions)

IdentityServer4 Authentication Server

API (Needs a JWT for back-end Authorization)

When someone first visits the client website a call is made to IdentityServer using the clientCredentials flow. This allows the user (Name: GUEST, user_id= null) limited access to the API (including adding items to a basket).

When the user logs in, they get a new token from IdentityServer along with new user claims (Name: BOB, user_id=1) which is fine.

My question is, how does the API know that the logged in user BOB was GUEST.

I have tried many things with IdentityServer including

1) Client Website: Add acrValue = client session.id but i can't figure out how to read this in Indentityserver and set it as a claim

2) Client Website: Add IdTokenHint = client session.id but, again, don't know how to read this in IdentityServer and set it as a Claim

3) Enabled 'IncludeJwtId' on my client configuration. When doing this a 'jti' claim is returned after a clientCredentials call but is missing after an implicit grant flow.

4) After an Implicit Grant flow the returned JWT has an 'sid' but is useless as it wasn't included in the original JWT from the clientCredentials flow.

I guess i would like to send a client sessionId as part of the clientCredentitals flow and also when the user logs in using the implicit flow. This way i could store the id in the JWT in both cases.

I feel like i'm missing something obvious. Does anyone know how i can maintain a sessionId across the clientCredentials flow and the implicit flow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how does the API know that the logged in user BOB was
>   GUEST.

I'm afraid that's up to your client app/API business logic.

> I guess i would like to send a client sessionId as part of the
>   clientCredentitals flow and also when the user logs in using the
>   implicit flow. This way i could store the id in the JWT in both cases.

And this is simple if you involve [delegation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html).